# Bean from controller to another

Tags: java, spring-mvc

How can I pass a bean from one controller to another? What I tried is:

Default get controller of the page

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/{prePath:[a-zA-Z]+}/module", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public String module( @RequestParam( defaultValue = "" )
String message, @RequestParam( defaultValue = "" )
String messageType, HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model )
{
     model.addAttribute( "message", message );
     model.addAttribute( "messageType", messageType );
     return "als-student/module";
}
```

Link to the controller

`<a href="../${ usertype }/module/${ file_id }.do" >Spring Tutorial</a>`

The another controller which only fetches the data from the database and suppose to send the data to another controller

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/{prePath:[a-zA-Z]+}/module/{file_id}" )
public String getModule( @PathVariable( "file_id" )
int fileId, Model model )
{
    try
    {
        FileBean fileBean = new FileDAO().getFileInfo( fileId );
        if( fileBean != null )
        {
            model.addAttribute( "fileBean", fileBean );
            return "redirect:../module.do";
        }
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "redirect:../module.do?error";
}
```

but i can't access it to the jsp, it shows nothing. Here is how I accessed it

`<p> ${ fileBean.fileName } </p>`

Comment: Go read what `Model` (and `HttpServletRequest`) attributes are and what a `redirect` does. And then read about flash attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `RedirectAttributes` to achieve this:

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/{prePath:[a-zA-Z]+}/module/{file_id}" )
public String getModule( @PathVariable( "file_id" )
int fileId, Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)
{
    try
    {
        FileBean fileBean = new FileDAO().getFileInfo( fileId );
        if( fileBean != null )
        {
            //model.addAttribute( "fileBean", fileBean );
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("fileBean", fileBean);
            return "redirect:../module.do";
        }
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "redirect:../module.do?error";
}
```

`Flash attributes` are saved temporarily before the redirect (typically in the session) to be made available to the request after the redirect and removed immediately.

Comment: Is there a down side to this approach?

Comment: spring framework reference doc recommends the use of flash attributes for redirect scenarios

Comment: How do I fetched the redirected model to the another controller? I tried adding to the model but it throws an exception

Comment: you can use `@ModelAttribute` annotation to your method parameter to fetch the data: `@ModelAttribute("fileBean") FileBean fileBean`